# In KDB, is there an equivalent of numpy's array.shape?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to work with matrices in KDB, and am frequently having to query their dimensions.

Currently I'm doing `count` and `count flip`, but this is verbose and repetitive. Is there a more elegant way to query the dimensions of an `n-D` matrix?

Comment: See depth and shape here: https://code.kx.com/phrases/phrases/

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are in front of a well formed matrix, a function that would achieve your objective is:

```
shape:{:(count x;count x[0]);};
```

If you use it very often, you can save in the startup file `q.q` in the `q` directory, so it is going to be loaded on launch and readily available.

Clearly, flipping the entire matrix is more expensive in terms of time:

```
t:(100;100)#til 10000
q)\t:1000000 {:(count x; count flip x);}[t]
33808
q)\t:1000000 {:(count x;count x[0]);}[t]
282
```

Having said that, the `flip` method will guarantee that the matrix is well formed, which is **not** going to be caught by the proposed method:

```
q)t2:((2;3;4);(2;3)) 
q){:((#)x;(#)x[0]);}[t2]
2 3
q){:(count x; count flip x);}[t2]
'length
[1]  {:(count x; count flip x);}
```